# How to watch Logs from Slog

Tags: android, logging

How can I see the logs generated from Slog API. Is there any option to see the logs from system buffer.

I mean to see logs from radio buffer we use

> adb logcat -b radio

And this log is generated by Android's Log class.

Where is the output of the Slog API? How can it be seen?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use:

```
adb logcat -b system
```

This outputs logging from the 'system' buffer, as opposed to the main or radio buffer.

Comment: But it is not working on Emulator? why? Isn't there system buffer in emulator?

Comment: You might need to run "adb root" first before accessing "adb logcat -b system".

Comment: @Neeraj Nama _"Isn't there system buffer in emulator?"_ It may vary. Shell into the emulator and `cat /dev/log` to see what you've got.

Comment: @Keeeeeenw _"You might need to run "adb root" first before accessing "adb logcat -b system""_ Emulator's `adb` is running as root by default.