# Print Slog in logcat (android.util.Slog)

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

Is there a quick way to print/enable Slog messages to view them in logcat? I know that system/radio/other buffers can be logged using `adb logcat -b xxx` command. I tried those, however they don't include Slog messages. Please suggest.

Slog example:
`Slog.v(TAG, "Raw acceleration vector: " + "x=" + x + ", y=" + y + ", z=" + z);`

Comment: should be `-b system` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278406/how-to-watch-logs-from-slog

Comment: Thanks @zapl. I tried that already, that doesn't include Slog messages.

Comment: there is an `if` that can disable this particular log. Did you check the source for the condition it requires to print that message?